# jquery tablesorter CSS arrow icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, icons, tablesorter

This is really more of a CSS question than a jQuery question.  I'm using the tablesorter jQuery plugin to sort tables dynamically.

Here's what it looks like currently:
[image]

Here's the CSS code that I'm using:

```
th.sortable{
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
}

th.headerSortUp {
    background-image: url("arrow-up.gif");
}
th.headerSortDown {
    background-image: url("arrow-down.gif")
}
```

The problem that I have with the current implementation is that the arrow is way over on the right of the header.  In the above example, the table is being sorted by level, but it almost looks like it could be by location.

Is there an easy way to move the arrow over to the left, so it's directly to the right of the end of the "level" label?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code or a link to an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place a `span` tag in your `th` and style it with:

```
th.headerSortUp span {
    background: url("arrow-up.gif") right center no-repeat;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would hardcode the offset to 15 pixels, right?  The problem with that is that the different headers have different label lengths.

Comment: It will hardcode a 15px offset from the inline element (span) :-)

Comment: and remove background-image: url(desc.gif); + background-image: url(asc.gif); background-image: url(bg.gif); from style.css

Comment: The padding is only to ensure the image is placed right next to the text. You can increase the padding to move it further away or contract it.

Answer (score 2):

```
th.tablesorter-headerUnSorted {
    background-image: url(/share/css/contextmenu/images/sort_both.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-position: right;
}

th.tablesorter-header {
    background-image: url(/share/css/contextmenu/images/sort_both.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-position: right;
}

th.tablesorter-headerDesc {
    background-image: url(/share/css/contextmenu/images/sort_desc.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-position: right;
}

th.tablesorter-headerAsc {
    background-image: url(/share/css/contextmenu/images/sort_asc.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-position: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
th.headerSortUp span{
    background: url("arrow-up.gif") right center no-repeat;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

th.headerSortDown span{
    background: url("arrow-up.gif") right center no-repeat;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

And add `span` to your `th`

**Edit:** Changed div to span (see coments below)

Comment: This will not function because of div is a block element and therefore width 100%;

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this worked:

```
table.tablesorter th.tablesorter-headerSortUp {
  background-image: url(../images/asc.gif);
}

table.tablesorter th.tablesorter-headerSortDown {
  background-image: url(../images/desc.gif);
}
```

Style.css downloaded from web cantained only `headerSOrtUp` class, but this works only with `tablesorted-headerSortUp` class, so they must have changed it.

Hope it saves some time to someone.

Answer (score 0):

If you cascade their stylesheet, it will look exactly the way it looks on the TableSorter site. You don't even need to move it from their package. Just add this line after your style sheet declaration:

```
<link href="[YOUR PATH TO]/tablesorter/themes/blue/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just missing the "tablesorter" class added to table. I added it and it solved. May this help somebody :)