# TableSorter: How can I change the position of sorting arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tablesorter

I'm implementing ***jquery***'s *tablesorter*. I need to change the *sorting arrows* position with respect to the *title* of the *column*.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-image: url(bg.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 80% 70%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This works fine for a *column* but not for the others where they overlap the *title* or go far to the right.
Is there a way to keep the *arrows* always show very next to the *column title*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using the default blue theme, all you need to do is change the background position of the arrows then add left padding to move the text away from it - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/92/)

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
    background-position: left center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}​
```

Comment: Note: this answer is meant for the original tablesorter v2.0.5. To move the arrow on my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), see @mezzoforte's answer.

Answer (score 4):

As of the latest `dataTables` v.1.10.4 *(on Dec 8 2014)*, they changed the name of the classes. 
In case you wish to put the sorting arrows on the left of the column title, the following CSS should be used get desired result:

```
table.dataTable thead .sorting,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled,
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled
 {
    background-position: left center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add a span after the column name where you change the class.. Like:

```
<tr>Column 1 <span class="sort-arrow" /></tr>
```

This question seems to be similar and provides a solution akin to the above: [jquery tablesorter CSS arrow icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509027/jquery-tablesorter-css-arrow-icons?rq=1)

Comment: But this places the sorting arrow precisely next to the column title, never overlapping the text? The point of my post was the <span> part where you add the background on instead of the <tr> cell. The changing mechanism can be replaced with your own.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the part about JQuery tablesorter (which I haven't used before).. Does the tablesorter inject the arrows into the markup or is that something you control?

Comment: You need to remove the class attribute from your span tag, it causes confusion.

Comment: I just put a class on it because I don't like "naked" tags (that is, tags with no content and no indication of what it does).. You are free to remove it of course.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer did not work for me. To keep the sorting arrows just to the *left* of the table header text, this worked:

```
.tablesorter-header {
  display: table-cell !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  background-position: left center !important;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.tablesorter-header-inner{
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

Comment: This css is actually for my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), my answer is targeting the original tablesorter v2.0.5.