# Sorting a table with columns composed of icons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter

I am using the [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) javascript plugin to easily sort a [bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables) table. My current code is simply:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.table').tablesorter();
});
```

My problem arises with columns that have no data but [font awesome](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) icons in, the check and the cross.

```
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
<i class="fa fa-times"></i>
```

Because there is no physical text in these columns, I am unable to sort them.

Aside of writing `Yes` and `No` beside the icon, is there any workaround to get tablesorter looking at HTML code instead of just text?

Comment: You could write "Yes" and "No" in a `<span>` tag next to your icons and just hide the tag, like this: `<span style="display: none;">Yes</span>` and see if it will sort on that.

Comment: Refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509027/jquery-tablesorter-css-arrow-icons

Comment: Thanks spryno, works a treat. If you put that in to an answer, then I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a `textExtraction` function to extract out the class names. [This example](http://codepen.io/Mottie/pen/GFjfK) extracts the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer, via spryno724 in the comments:

Add the `Yes` and `No` to the table cell, or to save characters, use `Y` and `N`.

Then, wrap them in a `<span>` and set it to `style="display:none"` in CSS.

The tablesorter plugin will read the `Y` and `N` and the table cells will become sortable, but the user will not be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this answer to your other similar question, but it was deleted for some reason.

Use the textExtraction function ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1446/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    textExtraction: function(node){ console.log( node.className );
        var $icon = $(node).find('i');
        return $icon.length ? $icon[0].className : node.textContent;
    }
});
```